# Dividing by the total count based on occupation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query where I am working out the percentage of peoples occupation. I have a sub query that works out the total count of people codes and that result is what I used to divide by. I could hardcode this but the count could change.

It just looks a bit messy and I am wondering if there is a nicer way to do the sub query.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),COUNT(CO.code)*100 / 
(
SELECT 
COUNT(CO.Code)
FROM 
TABLE1 K
INNER JOIN TABLE2 CO ON(CO.id= K.id AND CO.status= 'Something' AND K.statuscode = 0  AND CO.statuscode =0))
)+'%',
```

Here is the final query. I needed the sub query because of the group by which if I did the count in the `SELECT`, it would just return the number of people who had a specific occupation.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),COUNT(CO.code)*100 / 
(
SELECT 
COUNT(CO.Code)
FROM 
TABLE1 K
INNER JOIN TABLE2 CO ON(CO.id= K.id AND CO.status= 'Something' AND K.statuscode = 0  AND CO.statuscode =0))
)+'%',
K.occupation
FROM
TABLE 1 K
LEFT OUTER TABLE 2 CO  ON(CO.id = K.id AND CO.status = 'Something' AND K.statuscode = 0 AND CO.statuscode = 0)
GROUP BY
K.occupation
ORDER BY 
COUNT(CO.Code) DESC
```

Is there a nicer/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You missed the word JOIN on your LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Aliases

The aliases you have used in this query, `K` and `CO`, are meaningless. I would recommend using either the full table name, if it is short enough, or using a meaningful alias, such as `People`, `Jobs` or `Fruit` for a tables containing information regarding People, Jobs and Fruit respectively.

I would recommend always including `AS` when using an alias to prevent confusion.

## X = 0, X= 0 or X =0?

Okay first things first, you have examples of `X= 0`, `X = 0` and `X =0`. You should choose find a style you like and can read well and stick with it. I'd recommend `X = 0`. I find it easier to understand where each side of the statement ends with the separating spaces.

## Joins

Next, we have this bit:

```
INNER JOIN TABLE2 CO ON(CO.id= K.id AND CO.status= 'Something' AND K.statuscode = 0  AND CO.statuscode =0))
```

Firstly, you don't need brackets around the `ON` part of this. Adding the unnecessary brackets can just end up confusing you. If you had used a combination of `AND`s and `OR`s in the `ON` clause, then you would use brackets to make sure the statement is executed as you intended.

Secondly, you are checking that both `statuscode`s are 0 in the ON clause. The correct way to do this would be to make sure you only bring back records where the `statuscode`s are the same, and check one of the `statuscode`s in the `WHERE` clause.

Thirdly, `CO.status = 'Something'` should also be moved into the `WHERE` clause.

Lastly, is there a reason that the subquery uses `INNER JOIN` and the main query uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

## A Suggestion

Might I suggest removing the subquery and calculating the total number of jobs and storing the result in a variable? This should speed things up a little and make the main query a little easier on the eyes.

## Bringing It All Together

This is what I ended up with:

```
DECLARE @Total_Jobs INT = 
(
    SELECT COUNT(CO.Code)
    FROM TABLE1 AS K
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS CO 
    ON CO.id = K.id AND CO.statuscode = K.statuscode
    WHERE CO.status = 'Something' 
    AND K.statuscode = 0
)

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(CO.code)*100/@Total_Jobs)
FROM TABLE1 AS K
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 CO  
ON CO.id = K.id AND CO.statuscode = K.statuscode
WHERE CO.status = 'Something' 
AND K.statuscode = 0
GROUP BY K.occupation
ORDER BY COUNT(CO.Code) DESC
```